# INTUNE SDK Android Unable to read App configuration , configuration key values

Tags: android, android-studio, intune, intunemam

I am unable to read app configuration policy key/value set up . Below are the steps

### Repro Steps

**A copy of the source project with the issue is available at**
`https://github.com/franferns/intune-app`

1. Integrating the intune sdk creating a folder in the app folder with MAMSDK with
   [image]
2. Making changes to the root build.gradle file
   [image]
3. Making changes to app/build.gradle file adding reference to the sdk aar file
   [image]

and the settings.gradle file.

[image]

4. And then the code for accessing the config from the
   [image]
5. The app configuration policy configured is as follows
   [image]

**Expectation:**
To be able to read configured values app config policy "CustomerURL"
the value returned is null . Shown as a toast message.

**Observation:**
The code where we get an instance of the MAMAppConfig returns a object even on an non company portal device . Isnt it suppose to return null for no work profile (non company portal) related devices.

### Details

- **Intune Android App SDK Version:** Latest (10.0.0)
- **Android Device Make and Model:** Samsung Galaxy S21 5G/Moto G 5G/ Few other phones too
- **Android Device OS Version:** Android version 13
- **Android Studio Version:** Android Studio Electric Eel | 2022.1.1 Patch 1
  Build #AI-221.6008.13.2211.9514443, built on January 21, 2023
  Runtime version: 11.0.15+0-b2043.56-8887301 aarch64
  VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM macOS 14.1.1

**A copy of the source project with the issue is available at**
`https://github.com/franferns/intune-app`